# How to avoid writing two duplicate function f(*list), and f(list=[]) in python

Tags: python

I want to write a function to process both a [list parameter] and [several individual parameters]

For example: merging several string.
How can I write a single function (at least the same name, like overload in C++)

```
def merge_1(*list):
    return ''.join(list)

def merge_2(list):
    return ''.join(list)

print(merge_1('a','b')) #get 'ab'
print(merge_2(['a','b'])) #also get 'ab'
```

Comment: is the missing `)` in the last sentence a typo?

Comment: I would recommend just splatting the list as an argument to your function. Also avoid using built in names for variables.

Comment: Agreed. You only need `merge_1`, and can call it with `merge_1(*['a', 'b'])`.

Comment: sorry, updated  @BhargavRao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the equivalent of C++ overload, define `merge` as accepting an arbitrary number of arguments and inspect them:

```
def merge(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return ''.join(args[0])
    else:
        return ''.join(args)
```

However, doing this is not very *Pythonic*. Python functions are free to take advantage of the fact that they can be flexibly invoked with single or multiple arguments.

For example, if you choose to make `merge` a single-argument function, it can be easily called with an ad hoc list of strings using the `[...]` syntax, `merge([str1, str2, str3])`. Likewise, if you choose to make `merge` a multi-argument function, it can still be invoked with a pre-made list using the `*` syntax, e.g. `merge(*list_of_strings)`. The choice of whether `merge` will accept a single or multiple arguments is up to you and can be made depending on what is the more common use case. Your callers will easily adjust to both.

Comment: merge(str1, str2) & merge(*list) seems much more elegant Y(^o^)Y

Answer (score 1):

needs some improvements, but you can "dispatch" based on introspection:

```
>>> def merge(*args):
...     if len(args)==1 and isinstance(args[0], list):
...       return merge(*args[0])
...     return ''.join(args)
... 
>>> merge('a','b')
'ab'
>>> merge(['a','b'])
'ab'
```